# MapReduce: Which image processing algorithms are simplest to be implemented using MapReduce framework

Tags: algorithm, mapreduce

Though MapReduce may not be the best way to implement the algorithms used in Image Processing, just out of curiosity, which would be the simplest ones to implement if I were to try them out as a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is really well suited for large amounts of IO. So for example, you could make a job that blurs an image, using the algorithm in the [fork/join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) tutorial.

To do this, you'd create a MapReduce job with the following characteristics:

1. A Custom, non-splitable input format for each image.
2. A Mapper implementation that does the blurring.
3. An Identity Reducer.

[Here's a good post](http://eldadlevy.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/hadoop-binary-files-processing-entroduced-by-image-duplicates-finder/) that should get you started.